# Most economical way to manage and approve purchases through Family Sharing?

Tags: family-sharing

I have an older MacBook Pro whose hard drive has failed. I had been using this device mainly to approve app download/purchase requests from my children using Family Sharing.

The only other personal Apple device I have is an iPhone 4, which [does not have access](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7992901) to Family Sharing.

So my question is this: what is the most economical way to manage family sharing and app requests without buying a new Apple device?

I'm okay with a used device, an app or open source solution (running on a non-Apple OS), anything CLI based (again non-Apple OS) or even firing up an Apple VPS for a few minutes to approve requests.

Comment: How do you define economical? What value is your time? A used iPod touch or iPhone cost very little especially if you don’t pay for a data plan.

Comment: Good Q. I'm looking to minimize the $ amount out of pocket for about a year's worth of the ability to be able to approve app purchases. Let's value my time at zero as I'd be curious to try an interesting solution. Right now a $40 used iphone 5 is my most economical approach and I figure that'd last me about a year, but if I can flip on a mac mini in the cloud for a few cents a week to approve app purchase requests then that's what I'm interested in. The ultimate would be an API I can write a script for to periodically auto-approve requests for free apps or based on some other criteria.

Comment: Depending on the MBP model, it might be cheaper to just replace the drive. [People have vastly differing opinions on what constitutes 'older' ;) For some, it's 2018; for me I still have a houseful of perfectly functional Macs from between 2008 & 2012.

Comment: I have a 2011 model, it's been great but needs a battery, drive and charging block now! Thanks for the input.